# Placeholder overlapping on input focus

Tags: html, css

My input is overlapping with the text in its place holder after text is already in its spot.

[image: The Top is what I am trying to fix, and the bottom is what I want it to look like once you deselect the input field.]

My HTML For this Form:

```
<form action="./includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="emailuid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" name="pwduid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box">
        <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="login-submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my style sheet, just for this form and nothing else:

```
form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 45px auto;

}
form h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2196F3;
}
form h5 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #c6c6c6;
}
form hr.sep {
  background: #2196F3;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0px auto 45px auto;
}
form .emoji {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

input,
textarea {
  background: none;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4F4F4F;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label {
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
input:focus ~ .bar:before,
textarea:focus ~ .bar:before {
  width: 335px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

label {
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
}
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF3B3F;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
  left: 0%;
}

.btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #959595;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #752021;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.btn.btn-link {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: #d3eafd;
}
.btn.btn-link:hover {
  background: #0d8aee;
  color: #deeffd;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-submit:hover {
  background: #752021;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-cancel {
  background: #eee;
}
.btn.btn-cancel:hover {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.btn-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

To be clear I want it to look like the bottom "Password" field when you deselect from the box. The text when its on top of the input moves back down to the bottom and overlaps it when you are deselecting.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with jQuery `.focus()` and .`blur()` functions. First of all create a class with the *focused* style of your label. On input focus check if it has some value. If it has the `focused` class remains, otherwise remove it. Check the code bellow:

**css**

```
label.focused {
    top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).siblings('label').addClass('focused');
}).blur(function () {
  if($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('focused');
  }
});
```

**Full code**

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).siblings('label').addClass('focused');
}).blur(function () {
  if($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('focused');
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 45px auto;

}
form h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2196F3;
}
form h5 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #c6c6c6;
}
form hr.sep {
  background: #2196F3;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0px auto 45px auto;
}
form .emoji {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

input,
textarea {
  background: none;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4F4F4F;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/*input:focus ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label {
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}*/

label.focused {
    top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}

input:focus ~ .bar:before,
textarea:focus ~ .bar:before {
  width: 335px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

label {
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
}
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF3B3F;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
  left: 0%;
}

.btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #959595;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #752021;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.btn.btn-link {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: #d3eafd;
}
.btn.btn-link:hover {
  background: #0d8aee;
  color: #deeffd;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-submit:hover {
  background: #752021;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-cancel {
  background: #eee;
}
.btn.btn-cancel:hover {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.btn-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="./includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="emailuid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" name="pwduid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box">
        <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="login-submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For the jQuery part do i need to copy and paste the js code you provided into a document and save it?

Comment: Im just confused where to put the js that you posted for me to use. i put it in a <script>  and it didnt work with the css and html markup u provided.

Comment: Please put the js on the footer of your web page before `</body>` tag. First put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to import jquery and bellow that the script I suggest you inside `<script>` tags like this:  `<script>
  $('input').focus(function() {
   $(this).siblings('label').addClass('focused');
  }).blur(function () {
   if($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(this).siblings('label').removeClass('focused');
   }
  });
 </script>`

Comment: i added the script where you said and i linked the jquery before it. and it still does the deselect overlapping.. im really lost on why nothing is changing.

Comment: Did you add the class `focused` in your css too?

Comment: yes i copied your entire updated CSS and used that, along with your html markup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187395/discussion-between--papadakis-and-corey-rinda).